# When I show post category using <ul> tag its working but when I am trying to show post category in select box its not working

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

When I show the post category using the `<ul>` tag, it works, but when I try to show the post category in a select box, it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
<select>
<?php
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT catTitle, catSlug FROM blog_cats ORDER BY catID 
DESC');
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
echo '<option value="$val"><a href="c'.$row['catSlug'].'">'.$row['catTitle'].'</a></option>';
}?>
</select>

<ul>
<?php
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT catTitle, catSlug FROM blog_cats ORDER BY catID DESC');
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
echo '<li><a href="c-'.$row['catSlug'].'">'.$row['catTitle'].'</a></li>';
}?>
</ul>
```

Comment: `'<option value="$val">` will literally set the value as `$val` on all options. If you want to concatenate the value in a single quoted string, you need to do it the same way as you concatenate all the other variables: `'<option value="' . $val . '">`

Comment: ..and you can't have `<a>` tags in an option.

Comment: What does `$val` contain and what do you expect to happen when an option is selected? Do you just want a redirect?

Comment: Actually I was trying to load the post category using the option box. You can see it here: http://prntscr.com/jdkb4g

Comment: And I was trying to pass the url into the $val but I am not sure how to do this. Any help please?

Comment: You still haven't told us what you want to happen when you select an option.

Comment: When I select an option it should show post based on the post category that is showing in the drop-down menu.

Comment: Hi, made a few grammar edits for clarity.